# Trouble getting around list index error

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I've written some script to scrape Name and Price from craigslist. It works smoothly until it finds that either of the vale is None. As soon as It gets any None value it breaks displaying: "list index out of range". How to deal with that?

```
import requests
from lxml import html

page = requests.get('http://bangalore.craigslist.co.in/search/rea?s=120').text
tree = html.fromstring(page)
rows = tree.xpath('//li[@class="result-row"]')
for row in rows:
    link = row.xpath('.//a[contains(@class,"hdrlnk")]/text()')[0]
    price = row.xpath('.//span[@class="result-price"]/text()')[0]
    print (link,price)
```

Comment: one possibility is to surround the line that breaks in a `try`/`except IndexError: continue`, at least the loop *will* continue when it gets a `None` value

Comment: Thanks  downshift, for your answer. The problem with that is- It only prints those names which have prices but completely ignores those if either of the pair contains none value.

Comment: Yes, that's true @SMth80, if you put them into the *same* try block, but it won't ignore those names if you put each line into their own separate `try` clause. Each `try` block will attempt to get each name separately, and only catch an Exception if one *or* the other name breaks, then put the `print` in the `finally` block so it prints the results regardless if either `try` block breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most efficient technique by far I've come across to avoid errors.

```
import requests
from lxml import html

page = requests.get('http://bangalore.craigslist.co.in/search/rea?s=120').text
tree = html.fromstring(page)

def if_exist(row,xpath):
    docs=row.xpath(xpath)
    if docs:
        return docs[0]
    return ""

for row in tree.xpath('//li[@class="result-row"]'):
    link = if_exist(row,'.//a[contains(@class,"hdrlnk")]/text()')
    price = if_exist(row,'.//span[@class="result-price"]/text()')
    print (link,price)
```